# Is there something like Qt Designer for the web on Linux?

Tags: python, web-applications, qt-designer, cheetah, pyjamas

I'm very used to using Qt Designer to design GUIs, and I would like to be able to use something similar on a Python project I'm working on that I'd like to create a web interface for, but I find that a similar tool seems to be no where to be found.

Is there something like it that can perhaps generate a template (for something like Cheetah templates) or a PyJS interface visually like Qt Designer and connect it to the code (event handling), especially for Linux?